# Visual glitch when hovering over tags when trying to edit them in a post

Tags: bug, status-completed

As a power user, I'm able to edit the tags of a post directly on the question without having to go into edit mode and changing the tags.  However, when I tried hovering my mouse in order to edit the tags, I experienced a very weird glitch.  As I hover my mouse over the tags, the *edit tags* link keeps disappearing and reappearing.  When I start to move my mouse around in the vicinity, the boxes that show who edited the post as well as the OP start shifting horizontally to the right.

Animated GIF of this happening is shown below:

[image]

Currently using Google Chrome 58.0.3029.110 on Windows 7 Professional.  I've also experimented with Internet Explorer 11.  The hovering behaviour is normal and doesn't do this glitch.

Animated GIF of this is shown below:

[image]

Could this be a CSS error of some sorts? Apologies for my lack of correct use in terminology as I'm not a web developer.

Comment: [Affects all sites, reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296193/230261). Was waiting for that to show up here, ha.

Comment: @JasonC Got it.  Thanks. I should have checked MSE before posting.

Comment: No you did the right thing, I just like to post links to keep things organized. Also FYI the dev team reads the reports no matter where you post them.

Comment: I just came here to report the same issue. I'm using Safari on macOS. I love how the user's info slides off the right side of the screen as I move the mouse back and forth over the tags. Neat feature.

Comment: @rmaddy LOL.  It looks like IE and Microsoft derivatives don't seem to experience this problem / feature / easter egg.

Comment: i don't notice that, i already post a smilair question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349481/bug-edit-tag-of-a-question)

Comment: Chrome is experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The problem that I posted above is in Chrome.

Comment: @rayryeng What did you use to capture that in an animated form? I ask this because I posted a meta question about a flickering search icon and I'd like to possibly use the same thing/app you used in order to show its exact behaviour. However, if this requires an install, I may not be able to do that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I used licecap to capture the movements. http://www.cockos.com/licecap/. It requires a separate install so it may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng I might just give it a try, *cheers*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what happens when we try to make our sites [more flexible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296202/155160).

Comment: Ah huh.  Got it.  Thanks Adam!