# Bug - edit tag of a question

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I tried to edit the tags of a post, but it seems I can't click the edit button. [Here is a video](https://youtu.be/o4T73pAun20) describing what I mean.

I tried with both Mozilla and Google Chrome, latest versions.

Is this a bug, or a problem with my browser?

Comment: @JasonC i don't notice that

Comment: I see the bug too, even on this very page the `edit tag` link shows up under the tags when you hover over them.